# RegEx for data between . and {

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, regex, list

I am not very good in regex so I'm looking for help. I need to fetch content between `.` and `{`.

Example:

```
  .aaa  { }
  .bbb {}
   ccc {}
   ddd {}
   eee {}
```

I.e. `aaa` and `bbb` in a string. This data can change so I want to use a regex for this. Thanks.

Spaces are allowed and new lines are allowed. This is a simple text file.

Comment: `eee` is not preceded by `.`, but should be matched?

Comment: You don't need to be a regex-*god* to be able to use it. :)

Comment: @ Kevin, No it should not be matched

Comment: @ Bart: may be...still this is important n i dint wanna make any mistake in this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(?<=\.)[^{]*(?=\{)
```

will match everything between `.` and `{`.

Explanation:

`(?<=\.)` asserts that the preceding character is a dot.
`[^{]*` matches zero or more characters, anything except `{`.
`(?=\{)` asserts that the following character is a `{`.

To iterate over all matches in a string (C#):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<=\.)[^{]*(?=\{)");
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResults.Success) {
    // matched text: matchResults.Value
    // match start: matchResults.Index
    // match length: matchResults.Length
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: as i said i just want to selct data between . {   i dont wanna include ddd and ccc as they are not having . at the starting

Comment: Yes, and this is what this regex does. Is there a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to take all data between . and { and make a list.Using REGEX help from stackoverflow. I have replaced all \n,\r,spaces bye replacing it with blank. I have changed it a bit according to my needs.
This is my final function which has worked fantastically.

```
public static void MakeList(string s)
        {

            string PATTERN = @"(?<=\.)[^{]*(?=\{)";

            s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ","");
            var matches = Regex.Matches(s, PATTERN);
            var styleList = new List<string>();


            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
            {

                styleList.Add(matches[i].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler one:

```
\.([^{]*)\{
```

If you don’t want the spaces included in the results, use this:

```
\.\s*([^{]*?)\s*\{
```

Example of use:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"\.\s*([^{]*?)\s*\{"))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

This example prints “aaa” and “bbb” given your input.